# Using arguments pseudo-parameter as a writeable thing

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

In javascript, there is such thing as [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) pseudo-parameter, which allows to interact with function arguments dynamically. Now, while I'm listening to the lecture about javascript fundamental things & standards, there was a phrase:

*"Don't use `arguments` as a writable structure, always treat is as a read-only thing"*

I never used `arguments` to write there, so it's not a problem for me - but, really - I want to ask my

**Question**: are there any real use-cases when using `arguments` to write there is justified? If not, then why shouldn't `arguments` be used to write there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's suppose you're mad and you want to customize `console.log` so that doing

```
console.log("window.innerWidth");
```

would log

```
window.innerWidth = 775
```

which seems more convenient than doing

```
console.log("window.innerWidth =", window.innerWidth);
```

You could do it "properly", by building a new array or you could reuse `arguments` :

```
(function(){
  var stdlog = console.log;
  console.log = function(){
    if (arguments.length===1 && typeof arguments[0]==="string") {
      try {
       arguments[1] = eval('('+arguments[0]+')');
       arguments[0] += " =";
       arguments.length = 2;
      } catch (e) {} // in case it can't be evaled, do the normal thing
    }
    stdlog.apply(console, arguments);
  };
})();

console.log("window.innerWidth"); // window.innerWidth =  775 
console.log("Hello"); // Hello
```

Reusing `arguments` here would have the advantage of not having to build an array when you don't need it *and* not repeating the call to `stdlog`. The code would be less dry without that hack.

**Now, why you should not do this kind of things :**

- `arguments` hasn't been designed to be writable like arrays are, I had to set `arguments.length` explictly
- it's rather easy to simply slice the `arguments` object and to pass the resulting array as  *no accessible function needs an arguments object anyway*.
- using a native structure in a way it was really not intended to be used may lead to future incompatibilities
- it prevents optimizations. JS engines do **a lot** of optimizations without which many modern web apps wouldn't be possible. They give up optimizing in rare cases and [**some of them are related to arguments**](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#3-managing-arguments)
- **it doesn't work the same in strict mode and not strict**. Do you really want to have a function which would have a subtly different behavior if added (perhaps by concatenating files in a minification process) to a file having `"use strict"` ?

Here's a case in which the strict mode changes everything :

```
function incrNumber(v) {
  arguments[0]++;
  console.log(v)
}
```

In strict mode, the passed value is logged. In non strict mode, the incremented value is logged. And [that's the specified behavior](http://es5.github.io/#x10.6).

Comment: Hm. So you're saying that `arguments` shouldn't be used to write there just because it wasn't designed for that? Let's suppose, that setting length explicitly is a "cost" of such solution (so we won't treat that as a bad thing) - because we know that `arguments` isn't an array. Then - is your sample is a valid & justified use-case for writable `arguments`? Actually, I'm not sure if it's a _real_ use-case (because.. well, I'm not mad (I hope at least) and I won't implement `console.log` by my own)

Comment: @AlmaDo See edit. And I'd suggest reading https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#3-managing-arguments

Comment: Yes, I'm reading it. That's much, much like the thing I was looking for. So thank you for nice link (that was the case, when googling fails)

Comment: Actually, if a little less mad, you might want to define `console.val` instead of replacing `console.log`

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes it's convenient to write to arguments if you iterate over the arguments array.

### This is a hack, and is not encouraged.

```
var doSomething = function() {
   [].push.call(arguments, "process this too while you're at it");
   //arguments is not an array, so [].push.call is used to call push on it.
   for (arg in arguments) {
      console.log(arguments[arg]);
   }
}
```

### This is a hack, and is not encouraged.

Comment: Is it justified? If yes, when? If not, is it true that no use-cases for it exist?

Comment: @AwalGarg because its a hack?

Comment: Yes, and, actually, that is part of _my_ question (:

Comment: Because it's a lazy solution for what is usually a bigger problem. I'm currently on mobile so can't really improve right now.

Comment: @AwalGarg not really, since too much laziness now leads to a lot of headache later.

Answer (score 0):

I cant't think in any situation it would be useful, since the caller wouldn't be able to see the changes. I thought it would, maybe calling the function using the method apply, but I tried it on Chrome, and the arguments object is not the real list passed to apply.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your goals )
That's bad idea:

```
var a = 1;
function b() {
  console.log(arguments[0]); // <- 1
  arguments[0] = 2;
  console.log(arguments[0]); // <- 2
}

b(a);
console.log(a); // <- 1
```

There aren't any awful things. It's just useless.